# viewDidAppear stopped working out of the blue

Tags: ios, objective-c

All of a sudden my viewDidAppear is not getting fired upon pushing to a VC. 
What's strange is that is ALWAYS works on a certain segue.

```
 if (self.joinLabelSelected) {
        self.roomCodeTextField.inputAccessoryView.hidden = YES;
        [self.roomCodeTextField resignFirstResponder];
        self.menuView.hidden = YES;
        [self returnJoinLabel];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
            self.roomCodeView.alpha = 0;
            self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {  
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSetListRoomVC" sender:self];
        }];
    }
```

if joinLabelSelected == NO, then it will always work perfectly fine and viewDidLoad will work.

I'm using a navigation Controller and a custom segue with it.

```
@implementation CustomSegue
-(void) perform{
    [[[self sourceViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:[self   destinationViewController] animated:NO];
}
@end
```

WHY?! I can't think of anything I have changed that would cause this. Any ideas?

EDIT: Sometimes everything will work perfectly fine, and viewDidAppear gets fired and everything works. But as of the last hour, it has been working only about 25% of the time.